# Make an array from values belonging to a specific key in a dictionary (Swift 4)

Tags: swift, dictionary, random, key

I'm experimenting with dictionaries in Swift 4. I'm trying to make an array from a couple of values belonging to a randomly picked key within a dictionary. I'm not exactly sure how I need to do this in Swift 4.

```
//: Dictionary Test 

import UIKit

var database = ["Albert Einstein": ["Alberts first quote",
                                    "Alberts second quote",
                                    "Alberts third quote"],

                     "Martin Luther King": ["Martin's first quote",
                                            "Martin's second quote",
                                            "Martin's third quote"],

                     "Newton": ["Newton's first quote",
                                "Newton's second quote",
                                "Newton's third quote"]]

func randomQuote(){
    //Make an array from database keys
    var authorArray = Array(database.keys)

    //Pick a random author
    let author = (authorArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(authorArray.count)))])

    //Make an array from values based on the author we've picked (HERE'S THE PROBLEM)
    let quoteArray = Array(database[author].values)

    //Pick a random quote from the choses author
    let quote = (quoteArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray.count)))])

    print(author)
    print(quote)
}

randomQuote()
```

Now obviously `let quoteArray = Array(database[author].values)` is not working. Anyone an idea how this would work?

Comment: `database[author]` returns an optional, which you'll have to unwrap. This seems like one of the few cases where force unwrapping would be acceptable

Comment: Consider writing an extension on `Collection` that gives you a random element; then all you have to say is `let (author, quotes) = database.randomElement(); let quote = quotes.randomElement()` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lots of little things in `randomQuote` that need to be fixed.

There's no need for the 2nd use of `Array(...)`.

And `database[someKey]` already gives you the array of quotes.

You also have some extra sets of parentheses you don't need.

Here's the updated code with all the fixes:

```
func randomQuote(){
    //Make an array from database keys
    var authorArray = Array(database.keys)

    //Pick a random author
    let author = authorArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(authorArray.count)))]

    //Make an array from values based on the author we've picked 
    let quoteArray = database[author]!

    //Pick a random quote from the choses author
    let quote = quoteArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray.count)))]

    print(author)
    print(quote)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed there's no need for the second use of `Array(...)` however, I believe the first use of it is necessary in order to run this code without errors. Without it, it stores a LazyMapCollection into the variable which gives me problems when I try to `.count` it. Or do you have some workaround for it?

Comment: Yep, my bad. You do need the 1st use of `Array`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

database[author] is an array, not a dictionary. you need to do:

```
let quoteArray = database[author]!
```

Side note: surrounding things in parens when unnecessary is confusing as it make it look like a tuple.

Comment: Yea I know it was incorrect, it was just a bad guess. Thanks for pointing out how it does work. By the way, on what page in the swift book do they write about the use of `!` in dictionaries. I can't seem to find anything about it.

Comment: It has nothing to do with dictionary, it's a way to force-unwrap an optional. Getting a value from a dictionary returns an optional value, so you have to unwrap it to be used.